# AngularJS. Autorefresh $scope variable in html

Tags: javascript, html, templates, angularjs

How can I trig automatic my variable at $scope object?

```
//controller
setInterval(function(){$scope.rand=Math.random(10)},1000);

//template
{{rand}}
```

Rand is not update on my page. How can I update my variable?

Comment: what is $scope object? is it a variable for textbox?

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi That's an AngularJS thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.rand = 0;

  (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 1000);
    $scope.rand = Math.random() * 10;
  }());
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/udagop/1/

Answer (score 6):

Actually the most Angularish way to do that would be:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.rand = 0;

  function update() {
    $scope.rand = Math.random() * 10;
  }

  $interval(update, 1000);
}
```

That's the Angular equivalent of setInterval()

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
//controller    
function UpdateCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.rand = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
       $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.rand = Math.random(10);
       });
    }, 1000);            
}
```

and

```
//template
<div ng-controller="UpdateCtrl">
{{rand}}    
</div>
```